# Getting snapshot for some cells isn't working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I want to get snapshot for cell after long press and I get it working. I am creating snapshots by this code:

```
func customSnapShotFrom(view:UIView) -> UIView { // calling this with UITableViewCell input
    let snapshot:UIView = view.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(false) // here I tried true and false
    snapshot.layer.masksToBounds = false
    snapshot.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
    snapshot.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)
    snapshot.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    return snapshot
}
```

It's working but sometimes I get this message in output:

> Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty
>   snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before
>   snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

I get it only for some of the cells (just few) and not always. Sometimes it generates snapshot from that cell other time it returns nil. I've checked and I have always cell in input. So why is that? Why rendering results in an empty snapshot? Thanks

**Edit:**
I have added gesture recognizer to my tableView:

```
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressDetected:")
self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

And I am creating snapshot in `longPressDetected` method:

```
func longPressDetected(sender: AnyObject) {
    ...
    switch (state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began :

            ...
            let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
            snapshot = self.customSnapShotFrom(cell)
    ...
```

**My swift solution** thanks to [kirander answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32989253/367593):

```
func customSnapShotFrom(view:UIView) -> UIView {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let cellImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: cellImage)
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
    imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)
    imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
    imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    return imageView
}
```

Comment: From where you call this method?

Comment: I've edited my question. I've removed other code from longPressDetected method because I think it's not important to this problem.

Comment: Maybe it is because of cell getting selected? Try to turn off selection of cells.

Comment: My custom UITableViewCell which have this snapshot function is set to None Selection. But I can't disable selection for whole UITableView because I need some cells to be selected (but it is not cell which are used for snapshots).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code from [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=11280&start=10)

```
// make an image from the pressed tableview cell
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(inputView.bounds.size, NO, 0);
[inputView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *cellImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// create and image view that we will drag around the screen
UIView *snapshot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cellImage];
```

Comment: Although it is not fix of problem with `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates` function but it's working solution and I replace my code with yours. Thanks